# Run scripts from another computer

Tags: powershell, script, cmd.exe

I have a computer which I use from Jenkins builds, and a server which I've run multiple websites on.

When the Jenkins build is done, I want to stop the IIS on the server, copy all the files, and start the IIS when it's done.

I've created a script that copies the files after Jenkins is done, but how can I stop the IIS on the server from the Jenkins-computer?

Basically I want to run these two scripts:

iis_stop.bat:

```
iisreset /stop
```

iis_start.bat:

```
iisreset /start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iisreset` utility says it supports a computer name on its command line:

```
C:\> iisreset /?
```

Of course, your current logon account must have sufficient permission to do so.

Comment: Now I feel stupid for not trying this before. But thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [(Windows Sysinternals) PsExec v2.11](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-PL/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) :

```
psexec \\server1 -u domainname\username -p PASSWORD cmd && runas /user:administrator && c:\foldername\iis_stop.bat
```

Comment: On which computer do I install PsExec? On the Jenkins machine?

Comment: I get an error when running the command. Translated it's something like "Error communicating with PsExec service on xxx. There's no process on the other side of the pipe"-ish

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I get the same error. Do I have to do anything on the server? "Error communicating with PsExec service on xxx"

Comment: Same error =/ Could it have to do anything with firewall och settings on the server?

Comment: Sure, you need an access to the target computer.

Comment: Not recommended as `psexec` sends the password in clear-text over the network.